# Loop image addition laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to loop through adding images instead of hard coding each image. Is this possible?

```
            @if($listings->image2 ==! 'NULL')
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/cover_images/{{$listings->image2}}" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            @endif

            @if($listings->image3 ==! 'NULL')
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/cover_images/{{$listings->image3}}" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
            @endif

            @if($listings->image4 ==! 'NULL')
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/cover_images/{{$listings->image4}}" alt="Fourth slide">
            </div>
            @endif

            @if($listings->image5 ==! 'NULL')
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/cover_images/{{$listings->image5}}" alt="Fifth slide">
            </div>                    
            @endif

            @if($listings->image6 ==! 'NULL')
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/cover_images/{{$listings->image6}}" alt="Sixth slide">
            </div>                    
            @endif
```

our of interest, are there any benefits of having a loop instead of hard coding ? I'm sure the time taken will be negligible in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to have a specific rule to avoid failures, but take this code as an example

```
@for($i = 2; $i <= 6; $i++)
    @if($listings->{'image'.$i} ==! 'NULL')
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../storage/cover_images/{{$listings->{'image'.$i}}}" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
    @endif
@endfor
```

Comment: is there any benefit to loop it ?